# cocos2d xcode frameworks are not being added to the project

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have recently updated to Xcode 6.0.1.  I am trying to create an Cocos2d 3.x project.  When I do I get 200+ errors. The errors are due to the fact that the frameworks are not automatically being added to the project. I can go through and add them manually and fix the problem but this gets very annoying to repeat every time I want to create a new project. Can anyone tell me why the frameworks aren't being added? It used to work. I'm pretty sure the problem started when I updated to Xcode 6.0.1. Thanks.

Comment: You need to explain which version of cocos2d, how you install it, what you mean by frameworks not being added (did you mean templates?). After all, when you start a cocos2d project you do so from a template and the template in itself should be fully functional once you created a project with it. There's nothing in cocos2d that "adds frameworks" to a (existing) project. And since you are getting errors, please post a summary or excerpt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/something-wrong-with-the-xcode6/15437

Basically, the problem is in Xcode 6.0.1.  They recommend creating the project in Xcode 5 or SpriteBuilder and then opening it in Xcode 6.